# Uploading to AWS s3 bucket from Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to deploy my application's static content to AWS S3 bucket.

I am getting this error Error: Bucket mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com does not exist.

I have created a service connection and using that in the Task.
I am able to access the bucket directly via Cyberduck Tool with the same credentials as specified in the service connection.

Tried to use both these AWS S3 Upload Tasks
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools)
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MFelling.AWSS3Upload

Do I need to set any special permissions on the AWS bucket?

Update :
I have added the s3.createBucket and s3.HeadBucket in the AWS ACL. Now i am getting this error message
Error: Bucket .s3.amazonaws.com does not exist or you do not have access. Auto-create option not set, cannot continue.

Comment: Hi @Asha Bhawnani Did you check out below reply? How did it go? please let me if there is any question.

Comment: Hi @LeviLu-MSFT Grant access is checked for the aws service connection. But i am still getting the error

Comment: Hi @Asha Have you checked out the steps [here](https://medium.com/@wicaksono.nugi/deploy-asp-net-core-app-to-aws-eb-running-a-linux-using-azure-devops-part-2-cf6e147de014)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documents of AWS only says you need create an IAM User and Download Its Credentials. And supply the credentials to azure service connection for aws. Please check the details how to configure aws service connection.

Please double check the settings of your aws service connection in azure devops (try updating the **Access ID and Secret Access Key**).

And make sure `Grant access permission to all pipelines` is checked for your aws service connection in azure devops.

[image]

You can also check out [this bog](https://medium.com/@wicaksono.nugi/deploy-asp-net-core-app-to-aws-eb-running-a-linux-using-azure-devops-part-2-cf6e147de014) which gives an example in great details showing how to deploy to aws from azure devops.